# I Can`t understand what the condition mean

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements

What does this condition mean in Java?

`while(n&gt;0)`

I'm a newbie at Java and I've never seen this kind of code in conditions.

Comment: that is not completed...but means: ***Do while n is positive*** if possible take a look to [this doc article](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/118/basic-control-structures/470/do-while-loop#t=201708021356130099638)

Comment: seems like someone needs to look at a tutorial on while loops..

Comment: you really shouldn't post questions on this site that can be found with a quick google search.

Comment: Before I typed it here and submitted it was like "while(n&gt;0)" but now i see it`s been changed automatically! Now it`s obvious! :D But what is it exactly and when I need it? "&gt;0"

Comment: @Andrei &gt; is ">", the greater than symbol, hence gt. Where were you viewing this? seems like an error

Comment: Here is the link http://www.codezclub.com/java-program-find-reverse-number/

Comment: If you are seeing `&gt;` then it is error in source of that information. It seems that someone at some point was using `&gt;` to let browser print `>` but later changed way document is generated but forgot to change `&gt;` back to `>`. That is one of reasons why it is better to learn from official resources (problems like that are fixed faster).

Answer (score 1):

just do a search on while loop.
here is a link to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop)

```
while(n>10)
{
// do stuff..
}
```

.. simply means execute that block of code as long as n > 10.. normally you would have something inside that code block to make n greater than 10 at some point.. otherwise you would have an infinite loop.. which is bad..

Answer (score 0):

It means that as long as the variable named "n" evaluates to a value greater than 0, what ever logic is inside the while loop code block will continue to execute. FYI - a quick Google search will reveal thorough information and examples on while loops.

Answer (score 0):

the expression inside of a while loop is always a boolean expression; 
here you are expressing that a variable, n, is greater than 0. 
if true, you enter the loop, 
else, you do not.

For a situation like this, it is likely that n is an integer

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_while_loop.htm